# using "Grep" function with the number or repeats

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
df<- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), value = c("albert, collin, albert", "albert, albert, albert", "albert, nicole"))
```

that is

```
  id  value
  1 albert, collin, albert
  2 albert, albert, albert
  3         albert, nicole
```

Can I select the rows with **two** **albert**s?

Can I use `grep` with the number of repeats in R, so I can have this output?

```
 id  value
 1 albert, collin, albert
```

Comment: Is the goal to select the row(s) that contain(s) a specific duplicated string (`albert`), or the row(s) where any string is repeated a certain number of times (2 in your case)?

Comment: @MauritsEvers  The purpose is finding a certain number (it can be 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a `regex` approach but you can try.

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ","), function(x) 
                                     sum(grepl("albert", x))) == 2, ]


#  id                  value
#1  1 albert, collin, albert
```

Here, we split the `value` column by `,` and calculate the number of times "albert" is present in each row and take only those rows which has 2 "albert" in them.

Further you can also wrap this in the function and pass 2 as an argument for different values.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation from @RonakShah

```
nRep <- 2;
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$value), ", "), function(x) any(table(x) == nRep)), ];
#  id                  value
#2  2 albert, albert, albert
```

You can set the number of repetitions with `nRep`. If you want `nRep` as a lower bound, i.e. at least (or more than) 2 repetitions, use `table(x) >= nRep`.

Answer (score 1):

The base R function `gregexpr` will find multiple disjoint matches for a given pattern. You can use that to add a `count` column to your data, and subset on the count.

```
df$count_matches = sapply(X=gregexpr("albert", df$value), FUN=length)
df
#   id                  value count_matches
# 1  1 albert, collin, albert             2
# 2  2 albert, albert, albert             3
# 3  3         albert, nicole             1

df[df$count_matches == 2, ]
#   id                  value count_matches
# 1  1 albert, collin, albert             2
```